# How i can get Token from headers?

Tags: flutter

I did authorization via http. post, send a JSON Body with username and password, in the response I get a Header, the Header has a token, it is stored in 'set_cookie: Authorization=token', how do I get it and write it to the storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the cookie from the response of login request using the following code

```dart
HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpClientRequest request = await _httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
print(response.cookies); // this is a List<Cookie>, you can iterate and find the required cookie
```

Now you can store the cookie using [shared_preference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin, and use it in your all the future requests.

```dart
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpClientRequest clientRequest =
      await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http: //www.example.com/"));
clientRequest.cookies.add(Cookie("sessionid", "asdasdasqqwd"));
```

You can also explore [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) library and use `AuthInterceptor` to add the token for all the requests for you.

Comment: How i can get and print token in concole?
My code:
`String url = 'https://example.com/auth';
    Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'};
    String json = '{"login": "$username", "passwd": "$password"}';

    var res = await http.post(
        url, headers: headers, body: json
    );
    if(res.statusCode == 200)
    {
      print(res.headers);`

Comment: try to iterate `res.cookies`. It should have cookies.